# Dupe output to multiple cards

Tags: alsa, usb-audio

I am following the https://alsa.opensrc.org/Asoundrc `Dupe output to multiple cards` example on 2 stereo usb sound cards.

I changed things slightly but basically its the same as the above and 1 card plays a slightly rough rendition and the other is not much more than clicks.

So it becomes

```
pcm.!default plug:both

ctl.!default {
  type hw
  card 0
}

pcm.both {
  type route;
  slave.pcm {
      type multi;
      slaves.a.pcm "card0";
      slaves.b.pcm "card1";
      slaves.a.channels 2;
      slaves.b.channels 2;
      bindings.0.slave a;
      bindings.0.channel 0;
      bindings.1.slave a;
      bindings.1.channel 1;

      bindings.2.slave b;
      bindings.2.channel 0;
      bindings.3.slave b;
      bindings.3.channel 1;
  }

  ttable.0.0 1;
  ttable.1.1 1;

  ttable.0.2 1; # front left
  ttable.1.3 1; # front right
}

ctl.both {
  type hw;
  card 0;
}


pcm.card1 {
   type dmix
   ipc_key 1024
   slave {
       pcm "hw:1"
       period_time 0
       period_size 2048
#       buffer_size 8192
       buffer_size 65536
       buffer_time 0
       periods 128
       rate 48000
       channels 2
    }
    bindings {
       0 0
       1 1
    }
}

pcm.card0 {
   type dmix
   ipc_key 2048
   slave {
       pcm "hw:0"
       period_time 0
       period_size 2048
#       buffer_size 8192
       buffer_size 65536
       buffer_time 0
       periods 128
       rate 48000
       channels 2
    }
    bindings {
       0 0
       1 1
    }
}

ctl.card1 {
   type hw
   card 1
}

ctl.card0 {
   type hw
   card 0
}
```

Is the distortion due to the settings chosen for buffers... or am I doing something wrong or does alsa not work like this anymore?

Basically any method to aplay to a PCM where I get simultaneous playback on both cards with the same channels.